# Is the Lambda "Context" logger thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, lambda, thread-safety

Lets say i have this thread class in my lambda function...

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {

    private Context context;

    public MyThread(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override 
    public void run(){
        context.getLogger().log("I am using the context logger");
    }

}
```

And I create threads like this in the main handler class

```
while(someCondition){

    threadPool.submit(new MyThread(context));

}
```

Is this thread-safe? What if 2 or more threads want to use the context logger at the same time? If not, what is the solution to something like this?

Comment: Your `MyThread` is not a thread, it's a `Runnable`... And the class as shown is safe (adding final to the private field would not hurt). The question should probably be whether `Context` is thread safe or not...

Comment: Probably if you are using data of some object you don't need to worry about thread safety, you need to worry when you are modifying it.

Comment: What is “`Context`”? And what’s the relationship to “lambda”?